Retrieve email messages sent to a subscriber using Marketing Cloud Soap API
PROBLEM I'M TRYING TO SOLVE.
I want to get the date sent, subject and name of any email sent to a specific subscriber within the last couple months.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
I'm using C# to access the SF Marketing Cloud Soap Api.
BACKGROUND
I can successfully retrieve a Subscriber object using an email address as the filter.
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
rr.ObjectType = "Subscriber";
rr.Properties = new string[] { "ID", "EmailAddress", "SubscriberKey" };

SimpleFilterPart sf = new SimpleFilterPart();
sf.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
sf.Property = "EmailAddress";
sf.Value = new String[] { "email@test.com" };

rr.Filter = sf;

var retrieveResponse = client.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out Results);

Reading the documentation, it appears the next object I need to query is the SentEvent object.  Once the SentEvent object is queried I then need to query each sentEvent object to then get the Email object details for the sentEvent.
ISSUE
I am getting timeouts trying to query the SentEvent object.    Here is sample code that keeps timing out on the Retrieve call.
foreach (Subscriber subscriber in Results)
{
    RetrieveRequest rrSentEvent = new RetrieveRequest();
    rrSentEvent.ObjectType = "SentEvent";
    rrSentEvent.Properties = new string[] { "SendID", "EventDate" };

    SimpleFilterPart dateFilter = new SimpleFilterPart();
    dateFilter.Property = "EventDate";
    dateFilter.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.between;
    dateFilter.DateValue = new DateTime[2];

    //Use specific dates
    dateFilter.DateValue[0] = new DateTime(2024, 07, 01, 12, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime(); //BeingDate;
    dateFilter.DateValue[1] = new DateTime(2024, 08, 01, 12, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime(); //EndDate;

    rrSentEvent.Filter = new MarketingCloudApis.ComplexFilterPart()
    {
        LeftOperand = new MarketingCloudApis.SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator = MarketingCloudApis.SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new string[] { subscriber.SubscriberKey } },
        LogicalOperator = MarketingCloudApis.LogicalOperators.AND,
        RightOperand = dateFilter
    };

    APIObject[] sentEventResults;
    var status = client.Retrieve(rrSentEvent, out requestID, out sentEventResults);

Shouldn't this query of the SentEvent first look for those just sent to a specific subscriber and then filter them by the date?  We don't have thousands of SendEvents for each subscriber,  so I don't understand why the timeout issue.
Also, if my understanding of how to get data I'm looking for is incorrect, please let me know.
